# What is the best way to add options to a select from a JavaScript object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

What is the best method for adding options to a `<select>` from a JavaScript object using jQuery?

I'm looking for something that I don't need a plugin to do, but I would also be interested in the plugins that are out there.

This is what I did:

```
selectValues = { "1": "test 1", "2": "test 2" };

for (key in selectValues) {
  if (typeof (selectValues[key] == 'string') {
    $('#mySelect').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + selectValues[key] + '</option>');
  }
}
```

**A clean/simple solution:**

This is a cleaned up and simplified [version of matdumsa's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery/171007#171007):

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
     $('#mySelect')
          .append($('<option>', { value : key })
          .text(value));
});
```

Changes from matdumsa's: (1) removed the close tag for the option inside append() and (2) moved the properties/attributes into an map as the second parameter of append().

Comment: maybe of help: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/ (it was a help for me after i stumbled upon this question)

Comment: The cleaned up version listed above only works in Jquery 1.4+. For older versions use the one in matdumsa's answer

Comment: { value : key } should be { "value" : key } as seen in matdumsa's answer.

Comment: I don't believe so since `value` is a string (and hard coded) it doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: may be this would help you - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/add-append-insertoptions-select-options-using-jquery-javascript/

Comment: The title should be instead "What is the best way to add options to a select from a JSON object whith jQuery?

Answer (score 1485, accepted):

The same as other answers, in a jQuery fashion:

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
     $('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", key)
                    .text(value)); 
});
```

Comment: I would first of all assign `$("#mySelect")` to a var, otherwise calling `$("#mySelect")` every time inside the loop is very wasteful, as is updating the DOM. See points #3 and #6 at http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects

Answer (score 296):

```
var output = [];

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value)
{
  output.push('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
});

$('#mySelect').html(output.join(''));
```

In this way you "touch the DOM" only one time.

<strike>I'm not sure if the latest line can be converted into $('#mySelect').html(output.join('')) because I don't know jQuery internals (maybe it does some parsing in the html() method)</strike>

Comment: You method is obviously the faster one than the 'correct' answer above since it uses less jQuery too.

Comment: This breaks if the `key` has some quotes or `>, <` in it.

Answer (score 216):

This is slightly faster and cleaner.

```js
var selectValues = {
  "1": "test 1",
  "2": "test 2"
};
var $mySelect = $('#mySelect');
//
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
  var $option = $("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
  });
  $mySelect.append($option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Comment: It think it will be a better idea to cache ` $('#mySelect')` , so that you look up only once before the loop. Currently it is searching the DOM for the element for every single option .

Answer (score 114):

#### jQuery

```
var list = $("#selectList");
$.each(items, function(index, item) {
  list.append(new Option(item.text, item.value));
});
```

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```
var list = document.getElementById("selectList");
for(var i in items) {
  list.add(new Option(items[i].text, items[i].value));
}
```

Answer (score 41):

If you don't have to support old IE versions, using the [`Option` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) is clearly the way to go, [a readable and efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634509/1026):

```
$(new Option('myText', 'val')).appendTo('#mySelect');
```

It's equivalent in functionality to, but cleaner than:

```
$("<option></option>").attr("value", "val").text("myText")).appendTo('#mySelect');
```

Answer (score 33):

This looks nicer, provides readability, but is slower than other methods.

```
$.each(selectData, function(i, option)
{
    $("<option/>").val(option.id).text(option.title).appendTo("#selectBox");
});
```

If you want speed, the fastest (tested!) way is this, using array, not string concatenation, and using only one append call.

```
auxArr = [];
$.each(selectData, function(i, option)
{
    auxArr[i] = "<option value='" + option.id + "'>" + option.title + "</option>";
});

$('#selectBox').append(auxArr.join(''));
```

Answer (score 25):

A refinement of older [@joshperry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3841556/2):

It seems that plain **.append** also works as expected,

```
$("#mySelect").append(
  $.map(selectValues, function(v,k){

    return $("<option>").val(k).text(v);
  })
);
```

or shorter,

```
$("#mySelect").append(
  $.map(selectValues, (v,k) => $("<option>").val(k).text(v))
  // $.map(selectValues, (v,k) => new Option(v, k)) // using plain JS
);
```

Answer (score 22):

All of these answers seem unnecessarily complicated.  All you need is:

```
var options = $('#mySelect').get(0).options;
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
        options[options.length] = new Option(value, key);
});
```

That is completely cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 20):

```
 var output = [];
 var length = data.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
    output[i++] = '<option value="' + data[i].start + '">' + data[i].start + '</option>';
 }

 $('#choose_schedule').get(0).innerHTML = output.join('');
```

I've done a few tests and this, I believe, does the job the fastest. :P

Answer (score 20):

Be forwarned... I am using jQuery Mobile 1.0b2 with PhoneGap 1.0.0 on an Android 2.2 (Cyanogen 7.0.1) phone (T-Mobile G2) and could not get the .append() method to work at all.  I had to use .html() like follows:

```
var options;
$.each(data, function(index, object) {
    options += '<option value="' + object.id + '">' + object.stop + '</option>';
});

$('#selectMenu').html(options);
```

Answer (score 17):

There's an approach using the [Microsoft Templating approach](http://wiki.github.com/nje/jquery/jquery-templates-proposal) that's currently under proposal for inclusion into jQuery core. There's more power in using the templating so for the simplest scenario it may not be the best option. For more details see Scott Gu's post outlining the features.

First include the templating js file, available from [github](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Next set-up a template

```
<script id="templateOptionItem" type="text/html">
    <option value=\'{{= Value}}\'>{{= Text}}</option>
</script>
```

Then with your data call the .render() method

```
var someData = [
    { Text: "one", Value: "1" },
    { Text: "two", Value: "2" },
    { Text: "three", Value: "3"}];

$("#templateOptionItem").render(someData).appendTo("#mySelect");
```

I've [blogged](http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2010/07/08/using-jquery-templates-to-appendto-an-option-on-a-select-list-via-render/) this approach in more detail.

Answer (score 15):

I have made something like this, [loading a dropdown item via Ajax](http://www.chazzuka.com/blog/?p=206). The response above is also acceptable, but it is always good to have as little DOM modification as as possible for better performance.

So rather than add each item inside a loop it is better to collect items within a loop and append it once it's completed.

```
$(data).each(function(){
    ... Collect items
})
```

Append it,

```
$('#select_id').append(items);
```

or even better

```
$('#select_id').html(items);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
function populateDropdown(select, data) {   
    select.html('');   
    $.each(data, function(id, option) {   
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.value).html(option.name));   
    });          
}
```

It works well with jQuery 1.4.1.

For complete article for using dynamic lists with ASP.NET MVC & jQuery visit:

[Dynamic Select Lists with MVC and jQuery](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Dynamic-Select-Lists-with-MVC-and-jQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

The simple way is:

```
$('#SelectId').html("<option value='0'>select</option><option value='1'>Laguna</option>");
```

Answer (score 12):

Most of the other answers use the `each` function to iterate over the `selectValues`. This requires that append be called into for each element and a reflow gets triggered when each is added individually.

Updating this answer to a more idiomatic functional method (using modern JS) can be formed to call `append` only once, with an array of `option` elements created using [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and an `Option` element constructor.

Using an `Option` DOM element should reduce function call overhead as the `option` element doesn't need to be updated after creation and jQuery's parsing logic need not run.

```
$('mySelect').append($.map(selectValues, (k, v) => new Option(k, v)))
```

This can be simplified further if you make a factory utility function that will new up an option object:

```
const newoption = (...args) => new Option(...args)
```

Then this can be provided directly to `map`:

```
$('mySelect').append($.map(selectValues, newoption))
```

**Previous Formulation**

Because `append` also allows passing values as a variable number of arguments, we can precreate the list of `option` elements [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) and append them as arguments in a single call by using `apply`.

```
$.fn.append.apply($('mySelect'), $.map(selectValues, (k, v) => $("<option/>").val(k).text(v)));
```

It looks like that in later versions of jQuery, `append` also accepts an array argument and this can be simplified somewhat:

```
$('mySelect').append($.map(selectValues, (k, v) => $("<option/>").val(k).text(v)))
```

Answer (score 10):

There's a sorting problem with this solution in Chrome (jQuery 1.7.1) (Chrome sorts object properties by name/number?)
So to keep the order (yes, it's object abusing), I changed this:

```
optionValues0 = {"4321": "option 1", "1234": "option 2"};
```

to this

```
optionValues0 = {"1": {id: "4321", value: "option 1"}, "2": {id: "1234", value: "option 2"}};
```

and then the $.each will look like:

```
$.each(optionValues0, function(order, object) {
  key = object.id;
  value = object.value;
  $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', { value : key }).text(value));
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Rather than repeating the same code everywhere, I would suggest it is more desirable to write your own jQuery function like:

```
jQuery.fn.addOption = function (key, value) {
    $(this).append($('<option>', { value: key }).text(value));
};
```

Then to add an option just do the following:

```
$('select').addOption('0', 'None');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just iterate over your json array with the following code

`$('<option/>').attr("value","someValue").text("Option1").appendTo("#my-select-id");`

Answer (score 8):

1. `$.each` is slower than a `for` loop
2. Each time, a DOM selection is not the best practice in loop `$("#mySelect").append();`

So the best solution is the following

If JSON data `resp` is

```
[
    {"id":"0001", "name":"Mr. P"},
    {"id":"0003", "name":"Mr. Q"},
    {"id":"0054", "name":"Mr. R"},
    {"id":"0061", "name":"Mr. S"}
]
```

use it as

```
var option = "";
for (i=0; i<resp.length; i++) {
    option += "<option value='" + resp[i].id + "'>" + resp[i].name + "</option>";
}
$('#mySelect').html(option);
```

Answer (score 7):

A jQuery plugin could be found here: [Auto-populating Select Boxes using jQuery & AJAX](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/).

Answer (score 7):

That's what I did with two-dimensional arrays: The first column is item i, add to `innerHTML` of the `<option>`. The second column is record_id i, add to the `value` of the `<option>`:

1. PHP

   ```
   $items = $dal->get_new_items(); // Gets data from the database
   $items_arr = array();
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($items as $item)
   {
       $first_name = $item->first_name;
       $last_name = $item->last_name;
       $date = $item->date;
       $show = $first_name . " " . $last_name . ", " . $date;
       $request_id = $request->request_id;
       $items_arr[0][$i] = $show;
       $items_arr[1][$i] = $request_id;
       $i++;
   }

   echo json_encode($items_arr);
   ```
2. JavaScript/Ajax

   ```
           function ddl_items() {
               if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                   // Code for Internet Explorer 7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari
                   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
               }
               else{
                   // Code for Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 5
                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }

               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                   var arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                   var lstbx = document.getElementById('my_listbox');

                   for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                       var option = new Option(arr[0][i], arr[1][i]);
                       lstbx.options.add(option);
                   }
               }
           };

           xmlhttp.open("GET", "Code/get_items.php?dummy_time=" + new Date().getTime() + "", true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Although the previous answers are all valid answers - it might be advisable to append all these to a documentFragmnet first, then append that document fragment as an element after...

See [John Resig's thoughts on the matter](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)...

Something along the lines of:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(item in data.Events)
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.setAttribute("value", data.Events[item].Key);
    option.innerText = data.Events[item].Value;

    frag.appendChild(option);
}
eventDrop.empty();
eventDrop.append(frag);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way of doing it:

```
var options = [];    
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    options.push($("<option/>", {
        value: key,
        text: value
    }));
});
$('#mySelect').append(options);
```

Comment: I see what you did here... You took the advice to cache `$('#mySelect')` then refactored @rocktheroad answer... whatever, this is the more practical solution

Answer (score 7):

```
if (data.length != 0) {
    var opts = "";
    for (i in data)
        opts += "<option value='"+data[i][value]+"'>"+data[i][text]+"</option>";

    $("#myselect").empty().append(opts);
}
```

This manipulates the DOM only once after first building a giant string.

Comment: you can optimise this further and avoid the use of jQuery altogether by replacing `$("#myselect").empty().append(opts);` with `getElementById('myselect').innerHtml = opts;`

Answer (score 6):

I found that this is simple and works great.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $('#clientsList').append($("<option></option>").text(array[i].ClientName).val(array[i].ID));
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The JSON format:

```
[{
    "org_name": "Asset Management"
}, {
    "org_name": "Debt Equity Foreign services"
}, {
    "org_name": "Credit Services"
}]
```

And the jQuery code to populate the values to the Dropdown on Ajax success:

```
success: function(json) {
    var options = [];
    $('#org_category').html('');  // Set the Dropdown as Blank before new Data
    options.push('<option>-- Select Category --</option>');
    $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(i, item) {
        options.push($('<option/>',
        {
           value: item.org_name, text: item.org_name
        }));
    });
    $('#org_category').append(options);  // Set the Values to Dropdown
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the $.map() function, you can do this in a more elegant way:

```
$('#mySelect').html( $.map(selectValues, function(val, key){
    return '<option value="' + val + '">'+ key + '</option>';
}).join(''));
```

Comment: That is kind of shorter, but the one problem is dealing with escaping of the val and key vars which the accepted answer does do.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>append selectbox using jquery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function setprice(){
        var selectValues = { "1": "test 1", "2": "test 2" };
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
     $('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value)); 
});

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="setprice();">


      <select class="form-control" id="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $.each(response, function (index,value) {
                        $('#unit')
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", value.id)
                                .text(value.title));
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I combine the two best answers into a great answer.

```
var outputConcatenation = [];

$.each(selectValues, function(i, item) {   
     outputConcatenation.push($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.key).attr("data-customdata", item.customdata).text(item.text).prop("outerHTML"));
});

$("#myselect").html(outputConcatenation.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    $('#mySelect').append($("<option/>", {
        value: key, text: value
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your HTML select id into following line below. In here `mySelect` is used as the id of the select element.

```
   var options = $("#mySelect");
```

then get the object which is the selectValues in this scenario and sets it to the jquery for each loop. It will use the value and text of the objects accordingly and appends it into the option selections as follows.

```
$.each(selectValues, function(val, text) {
            options.append(
             $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
          );
      });
```

This will display text as the option list when drop down list is selected and once a text is selected value of the selected text will be used.

Eg.

"1": "test 1", 
"2": "test 2",

Dropdown,

display name: test 1 -> value is 1
display name: test 2 -> value is 2

Comment: please describe a bit about the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for getting the improved performance, it's better to make option list separately and append to select id.

```
var options = [];
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    options.push ($('<option>', { value : key })
          .text(value));
});
 $('#mySelect').append(options);
```

http://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/

Answer (score 2):

## Pure JS

In pure JS adding next option to select is easier and more direct

```or-tag-here
mySelect.innerHTML+= `<option value="${key}">${value}</option>`;
```

```js
let selectValues = { "1": "test 1", "2": "test 2" };

for(let key in selectValues) { 
  mySelect.innerHTML+= `<option value="${key}">${selectValues[key]}</option>`;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">test 0</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to chime in a bit.

1. Deal with prior selected option; some browsers mess up when we append
2. ONLY hit DOM once with the append
3. Deal with `multiple` property while adding more options
4. Show how to use an object
5. Show how to map using an array of objects

```js
// objects as value/desc
let selectValues = {
  "1": "test 1",
  "2": "test 2",
  "3": "test 3",
  "4": "test Four"
};
//use div here as using "select" mucks up the original selected value in "mySelect"
let opts = $("<div />");
let opt = {};
$.each(selectValues, function(value, desc) {
  opts.append($('<option />').prop("value", value).text(desc));
});
opts.find("option").appendTo('#mySelect');

// array of objects called "options" in an object
let selectValuesNew = {
  options: [{
      value: "1",
      description: "2test 1"
    },
    {
      value: "2",
      description: "2test 2",
      selected: true
    },
    {
      value: "3",
      description: "2test 3"
    },
    {
      value: "4",
      description: "2test Four"
    }
  ]
};

//use div here as using "select" mucks up the original selected value
let opts2 = $("<div />");
let opt2 = {}; //only append after adding all options
$.map(selectValuesNew.options, function(val, index) {
  opts2.append($('<option />')
    .prop("value", val.value)
    .prop("selected", val.selected)
    .text(val.description));
});
opts2.find("option").appendTo('#mySelectNew');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" selected="selected">empty</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelectNew" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected">2empty</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JQuery's `append` can take an array as an argument, I'm surprised nobody suggested making this a one-liner with `map`

```
$('#the_select').append(['a','b','c'].map(x => $('<option>').text(x)));
```

or `reduce`

```
['a','b','c'].reduce((s,x) => s.append($('<option>').text(x)), $('#the_select'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the object keys to get the object values.
Using map() to add new Options.

```js
const selectValues = {
  "1": "test 1",
  "2": "test 2"
}
const selectTest = document.getElementById('selectTest')
Object.keys(selectValues).map(key => selectTest.add(new Option(selectValues[key], key)))
```

```html
<select id="selectTest"></select>
```