# jQuery: add an <option> to a <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

When I attempt to add an `option` to a `select`, the `option` I’m trying to append ends up appended to the first `option` instead of the `select` itself.

```js
$(".ct [value='']").each(function() {
    $(this).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "Reset").text("Reset"));
});
```

Help?

Comment: Do you want to add as much options as the number of empty valued options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd have to see the HTML you're targetting to be sure, but it looks to me like your selector is targetting the first option of the select.

Try $(this).parent.append() instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(this).parent().append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "Reset").text("Reset"));
```

Comment: But this adds options equal to the number of empty valued options. So better change the selector.