# thickbox help to call method from parent html on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, thickbox

I use thickbox to load an html. This html has a form that i need to add some stuff to the database. I have a select box in the main html (the one that i load thickbox from). 
What i want to do is when i press the close button in thickbox, the select box has to be updated with the stuff i just added in the database. I was thinking to modify the thickbox close method and to call my method that updates the select box but thickbox crashes when i do that. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thickbox is getting pretty old, and it's not maintained any more. Are you using it by choice or are you forced to use it in an old application?  Anyway, wouldn't you want to update the "select" list when the form submission returns?  How are you submitting the form anyway?

Comment: i am using it by choice. if you know any other alternative i am open to suggestions.

Comment: The thickbox home page lists alternatives: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: @user253530 - can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 8):

you can also 'hijack' the whole tb_remove function.
this means that you will not only capture the link click but also the ESC key press..

this involves renaming the original remove method inline and substituting it with your own.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var original_tb_remove = tb_remove;
        tb_remove = function () { 
                  **** insert your coolness here ****
                  original_tb_remove(); 
                  return false; } 
    </script>
```

Note: make sure you do this before thickbox is first called for maximum success.

Comment: @mathlight glad to hear I helped someone even this long after :)

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the thickbox in action using Firebug, you can see that the thickbox modal is actually a div inside the main page. You can just call any function in the main page from the thickbox.

For example, this code will 'hijack' the thickbox close link and do extra stuffs:

```
$("#TB_closeWindowButton").click(function(){
  tb_remove();
  //do extra stuffs, such as get a new select
  var select_parent = $('#theselect').parent();
  $.get('new_select.php',
        {},
        function(data){
          select_parent.html(data);
        });
});
```

Beside hijack the thickbox close link, you can also put the code into any link inside the thickbox. Just make sure you call `tb_remove()` to close the thickbox window, before or after your custom code. If it involve submitting a form, use [jQuery form plugins](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form) to submit the form via AJAX, and then run your close function on a successful form submit.

About updating the select box, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery/1678839#1678839) about how to do make it run in every browser.

To make sure that your function always called, you can set the thickbox to use `modal` mode that will disable the escape key. Remember to put the close code, because by default, the thickbox bar will not displayed.