# Javascript hide items from dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list with 24 items, the user can check a radio button and this will set it to only show 12. If they de-select it, the dropdown will show the 24 items as before.

I have it working to only show 12 items using

```
document.getElementById('theMenu').length = 12;
```

But then when I try to set it back to 24, the other 12 items are empty.

Am thinking I may need to store the values in a temp array of some sort, then just load these back into the dropdown menu? (Javascript only)

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes setting the length to 12 is destroying the second 12 values.

It may be benifical to put these elements in memory when the page is ready and not to manipulate that array (use it as a constant), populate another array with ones you need, create a method that takes an array and populates a drop down (you could hard-code the target array, or make the target Id another parameter).

Are you able to use the JQuery library? I would suggest so. It will most probably have some useful methods for manipulating `<select>`s.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the best choice. I would use JQuery but as its for my assignment it has to be plain javascript :).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery to make it simpler?

You can store the values in an Array

```
var values = {1:one,2:two,3:three};
```

and then based on the checkbox value populate them

```
$.each(values , function(key,value) { 
  alert(value); 
       $('#drop').
          append($("<option></option>").
          attr("value",key).
          text(key)); 

});
```

---

[What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Comment: I would, but am doing this for my assignment. I don't actually have to do this, but I like to add more functionality :), thanks.