# add elements to select html tag with jquery at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select tag that looks like that:

```
<select name="MySelect"></select>
```

At runtime, I have a javascript function that composes some HTML and returns a string that looks like this:

```
TheOptions = <option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option>
```

I want to add these to the select tag and so far I have:

```
$('#MySelect').html(TheOptions);
```

However, when the code executes, it doesn't load the options in the selector.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it executes after `$(document).ready` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `select` element

```
<select name="MySelect"></select>
```

Isn't selected by the jQuery selector:

```
$('#MySelect').html(TheOptions);
```

The use of the `#MySelect` is an `id` based selector, whereas your `select` has only a `name` attribute; so instead, you could use:

```
$('input[name="MySelect"]').html(TheOptions);
```

Although I'd be more tempted to suggest that you use, instead:

```
$(TheOptions).appendTo($('input[name="MySelect"]'));
```

Reference:

- [attribute-equals `[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Comment: Thanks: I changed <select name="MySelect" id="TheSelect"></select> and the jquery to $('#TheSelect').html(TheOptions);

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change `name` to `id`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3pWLc/1/

Comment: If he *changes* the `name` to `id` then how will he retrieve the submitted values? (I'm assuming a submission to a server-side script, obviously).

Comment: Perfectly valid point- of course you could add a separate name or change the selector.  FWIW I upvoted your answer for completeness before I submitted mine- I'd already made the jsfiddle so I posted anyway.  We can continue the shameless race for JQuery reputation points in five minutes if he's not able to figure it out and posts again.

Comment: That's one of the few times I've ever, literally, laughed at a comment, thank you for that =) my own shameless race is, however, finished until tomorrow evening. +1, and the best of luck to you in the interminable pursuit of jQuery rep! =D

Answer (score 0):

[What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

That has a really good answer for how to do this.

But the `$("#Blah)` refers to the id attribute, not the name.  So adding the id attr to the `<select/>` will fix it