# Adding select element through javascript doesn't work in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select

my code works fine in Safari, and FF, but in IE the drop down is empty.  Its just empty.  Any ideas?  This is jquery-1.5.  Thanks!

```
var sel = document.createElement("select");
sel.setAttribute("id", key)
sel.setAttribute('name', key)
for (var option in ddHash[key]){
    var optElement = document.createElement("option")
    optElement.text = ddHash[key][option]
    if (// some conditional){
        optElement.selected = true
    }
    else {
        optElement.selected = false
    }
    sel.appendChild(optElement)
}
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not [use jQuery methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `optElement.text` should be `optElement.innerText` for IE.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN reference for the [`option` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> You can create new OPTION elements
>   dynamically with the
>   document.createElement method, but you
>   cannot change properties until the new
>   element is added to a SELECT object.
>   Or, you can create fully formed
>   elements by using the Option object,
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> var opt = new Option( 'Text', 'Value', fDefaultSelected );
> ```

So it seems you just need to call `appendChild` before trying to set the properties.