# How to bind <select> from list of comma separated values in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

How we can bind select tag with variable data?..

Here is my sample code here.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var google.language.Languages = {
  'AFRIKAANS' : 'af',
  'ALBANIAN' : 'sq',
  'AMHARIC' : 'am',
  'ARABIC' : 'ar',
  'ARMENIAN' : 'hy',
  'AZERBAIJANI' : 'az' ...
}
</script>
```

I want Bind my select tag using above languages

```
<select id="langsel" name="selector">
        <option value="">Select a language</option>
</select>
```

How to bind "**langsel**" select with above variable.?

**I need output like below** :

```
 <select id="langsel" name="selector">
            <option value="">Select a language</option>
            <option value="af">AFRIKAANS</option> 
            ....
    </select>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    var languages = {
      'AFRIKAANS' : 'af',
      'ALBANIAN' : 'sq',
      'AMHARIC' : 'am',
      'ARABIC' : 'ar',
      'ARMENIAN' : 'hy',
      'AZERBAIJANI' : 'az'
    }

    var sel = $('#langsel');

    $.each(languages, function(key, value) { 
        sel.append('<option value="'+value+'">'+key+'</option>');
    });

});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtb6S/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here: [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Loop through your languages in a for loop, and use the code in that answer above.

Answer (score 1):

```
var languages = [
  'AFRIKAANS : af',
  'ALBANIAN : sq',
  'AMHARIC : am',

]

$.each(languages,function(index,elem){
    $("#langsel").append(

    $("<option/>").val(elem.split(':')[1]).text(elem.split(':')[0])

    );
});
```

**fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3dFgg/**

Answer (score 0):

The quickest (to type) way to do it would be to first build the HTML string, and then insert it into the `<select>`:

```
var languages = { /* ... */ },
    str = '',
    hop = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
    x;

for (x in languages) {
    if (hop.call(languages, x)) {
        str += '<option value="' + languages[x] + '">' + x + '</option>';
    }
}
document.getElementById('langsel').innerHTML += str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var sel = $("#langsel");
var html = "";
var items = Languages;
html =  $("<option></option>").text("Select a Language").val(""); 
sel.append(html);
html = "";
for (var index in items) {
    html = $("<option></option>").text(index).val(items[index]);
    sel.append(html);
    html = "";
}
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FXta5/

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this manually, but for fun, this is the sort of thing [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) are designed to do. The [`{{each}}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/) tag will let you iterate over an array or object, building some dynamic HTML as you go.

First set up the template:

```
<script id="optionTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(lang,abbrev) $data}}
    <option value="${abbrev}">${lang}</option>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here's the empty HTML `<select>` to be filled with new `<option>` tags:

```
<select id="langsel" name="selector">
    <option value="">Select a language</option>
</select>
```

Your language object:

```
var langs = {
    'AFRIKAANS': 'af',
    'ALBANIAN': 'sq',
    'AMHARIC': 'am',
    'ARABIC': 'ar',
    'ARMENIAN': 'hy',
    'AZERBAIJANI': 'az'
};
```

Then the easy part:

```
$("#optionTemplate").tmpl(langs).appendTo("#langsel");
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/nHtH3/