# Add <options> dynamically to HTML <select> tag in Jquery UI dialog widget

Tags: jquery-ui

I require to add options dynamically to drop down menu in a jquery ui dialog. My code is in php so i'll have to pass the variables to javascript function for jquery and use these values to make the drop down list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Send the options out of PHP as an array or JSON decoded data
2. In Javascript when you create a dialog box you can run a function on dialog open. Use this as an opportunity to populate options.
3. Select the /select box/ element and append select box with options.

If need help visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)