# Adding options to select with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want this javascript to create options from 12 to 100 in a select with id="mainSelect", because I do not want to create all of the option tags manually. Can you give me some pointers? Thanks

```
function selectOptionCreate() {

  var age = 88;
  line = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    line += "<option>";
    line += age + i;
    line += "</option>";
  }

  return line;
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the linked 'duplicate' only has jQuery-based answers, whereas this one requires (or at least implies a requirement of) plain JavaScript.

Comment: [Great answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17730724/1028230): `mySelect.options[mySelect.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');`

Answer (score 389, accepted):

You could achieve this with a simple `for` loop:

```
var min = 12,
    max = 100,
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NX3ac/).

[JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/) comparison of both mine and [Sime Vidas' answer](http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-loops), run because I thought his looked a little more understandable/intuitive than mine and I wondered how that would translate into implementation. According to Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04 mine is somewhat faster, other browsers/platforms are likely to have differing results though.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP:

> [How] do [I] apply this to more than one element?

```
function populateSelect(target, min, max){
    if (!target){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var min = min || 0,
            max = max || min + 100;

        select = document.getElementById(target);

        for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = i;
            opt.innerHTML = i;
            select.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
}
// calling the function with all three values:
populateSelect('selectElementId',12,100);

// calling the function with only the 'id' ('min' and 'max' are set to defaults):
populateSelect('anotherSelect');

// calling the function with the 'id' and the 'min' (the 'max' is set to default):
populateSelect('moreSelects', 50);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NX3ac/1/).

And, finally (after quite a delay...), an approach extending the prototype of the `HTMLSelectElement` in order to chain the `populate()` function, as a method, to the DOM node:

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.populate = function (opts) {
    var settings = {};

    settings.min = 0;
    settings.max = settings.min + 100;

    for (var userOpt in opts) {
        if (opts.hasOwnProperty(userOpt)) {
            settings[userOpt] = opts[userOpt];
        }
    }

    for (var i = settings.min; i <= settings.max; i++) {
        this.appendChild(new Option(i, i));
    }
};

document.getElementById('selectElementId').populate({
    'min': 12,
    'max': 40
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NX3ac/148/).

References:

- [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/node.appendChild).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).

Comment: @Jack: agreed, and I've used that approach in the latter edit :)

Comment: Also, extending host prototypes (while tempting) is considered a [*bad idea*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: I think this should be updated to use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to avoid cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. What do you think @DavidThomas?

Answer (score 60):

The most concise and intuitive way would be:

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById('ageselect');

for (var age = 12; age <= 100; age++) {
  selectElement.add(new Option(age));
}
```

```html
Your age: <select id="ageselect"><option value="">Please select</option></select>
```

You can also differentiate the name and the value or add items at the start of the list with additional parameters to the used functions:
[HTMLSelect​Element​.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)(item[, before]);
[new Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);

Answer (score 28):

Here you go:

```
for ( i = 12; i <= 100; i += 1 ) {
    option = document.createElement( 'option' );
    option.value = option.text = i;
    select.add( option );
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mwPb5/

---

**Update:** Since you want to reuse this code, here's the function for it:

```
function initDropdownList( id, min, max ) {
    var select, i, option;

    select = document.getElementById( id );
    for ( i = min; i <= max; i += 1 ) {
        option = document.createElement( 'option' );
        option.value = option.text = i;
        select.add( option );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
initDropdownList( 'mainSelect', 12, 100 );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mwPb5/1/

Comment: how do i apply this to more than one element?

Answer (score 14):

I don't recommend doing DOM manipulations inside a loop -- that can get expensive in large datasets. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
var elMainSelect = document.getElementById('mainSelect');

function selectOptionsCreate() {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    elOption;
  for (var i=12; i<101; ++i) {
    elOption = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    elOption.text = i;
  }
  elMainSelect.appendChild(frag);
}
```

You can read more about DocumentFragment on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), but here's the gist of it:

> It is used as a light-weight version of Document to store a segment of
>   a document structure comprised of nodes just like a standard document.
>   The key difference is that because the document fragment isn't part of
>   the actual DOM's structure, changes made to the fragment don't affect
>   the document, cause reflow, or incur any performance impact that can
>   occur when changes are made.

Answer (score 6):

The one thing I'd avoid is doing DOM operations in a loop to avoid repeated re-renderings of the page.

```
var firstSelect = document.getElementById('first select elements id'),
    secondSelect = document.getElementById('second select elements id'),
    optionsHTML = [],
    i = 12;

for (; i < 100; i += 1) {
  optionsHTML.push("<option value=\"Age" + i + "\">Age" + i + "</option>";
}

firstSelect.innerHTML = optionsHTML.join('\n');
secondSelect.innerHTML = optionsHTML.join('\n');
```

Edit: removed the function to show how you can just assign the html you've built up to another select element - thus avoiding the unnecessary looping by repeating the function call.

Comment: how do i apply this to more than one element?

Comment: Not sure I follow - you want to add the same options to more than one select element?

Comment: Yeah, I want to boxes with the same options

Comment: I factored it into a function you can call where you just pass in the id of the select element you want to append the options to.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to bother with a function, just set the innerHTML of the other select element with the optionsHTML.join('\n') call at the end of the function.

Comment: That's what documentFragment is made for. You can easily modify the accepted answer so that options would be appended to documentFragment at first, preventing multiple renderings.

Comment: The DOM will be updated multiple times, but the page won't be re-rendered until after the JS finishes.

Comment: For better performance, I mean if I want to avoid multiple DOM rendering, this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new `Option` object, there are two parameters to pass: The first is the text you want to
appear in the list, and the second the value to be assigned to the option.

```
var myNewOption = new Option("TheText", "TheValue");
```

You then simply assign this `Option` object to an empty array element, for example:

```
document.theForm.theSelectObject.options[0] = myNewOption;
```

Answer (score 4):

See: [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

```
$('#mySelect')
      .append($('<option>', { value : key })
      .text(value));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('ageselect');

for (var age = 12; age <= 100; age++) {
  selectElement.add(new Option(age, age));
}


Your age: <select id="ageselect"><option value="">Please select</option></select>
```

Notice the value was added as a second parameter to new Option

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Append method didn't give error when i tried but it didn't solve my problem. In the end i solved my problem with data property of select2. I used json and got the array and then give it in select2 element initialize. For more detail you can see my answer at below post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41297283/4928277

Answer (score 0):

Often you have an array of related records, I find it easy and fairly declarative to fill `select` this way:

```
selectEl.innerHTML = array.map(c => '<option value="'+c.id+'">'+c.name+'</option>').join('');
```

This will replace existing options.
You can use `selectEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', str);` to add them to the top instead.
And `selectEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);` to add them to the bottom of the list.

IE11 compatible syntax:

```
array.map(function (c) { return '<option value="'+c.id+'">'+c.name+'</option>'; }).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 12; i< 101; i++){
    let html = ""
    html += `
        <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
    `
    mainSelect.innerHTML += html
}
```

```html
const mainSelect = document.getElementById("mainSelect")
```

This is a very easy-to-understand way to solve your problem! Hope it heps:)

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 I would do it like this:

```
const elmainSelect = document.getElementById('mainSelect');
for (var i = 12; i < 101; i++) Object.assign(elmainSelect.appendChild(document.createElement('option')), {value: i, text: i});
```

```js
const elmainSelect = document.getElementById('mainSelect');
for (var i = 12; i < 101; i++) Object.assign(elmainSelect.appendChild(document.createElement('option')), { value: i + 159, text: i });
elmainSelect.value = 171;
elmainSelect.addEventListener('change', () => document.getElementById('blink').innerHTML = Number(elmainSelect.value) === 182 ? `Nobody likes you when you're twenty-three` : 'My friends say I should act my age');
```

```html
What's my age again?
<select id="mainSelect"></select>
<div id="blink"></div>
```