# Add options to Select2 after inititialzation

Tags: jquery-select2

This seems like a standard thing to want to do, but I'm struggling to find a clear and simple solution.

I want to be able to add one or more additional options to an already initialized Select2.

I am using an older version of Select2, not sure what the version is off hand though.

Answer (score 24):

You can solve most questions involving Select2 in the same way that they would be solved in a standard `<select>`. In this case, the corresponding `<select>` question would be: [Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8674618/359284).

```
var option = new Option("text", "id");
$("select").append(option);
```

If you want it to be selected when it is inserted, you can just set the `selected` property on the new option.

```
var option = new Option("text", "id");
option.selected = true;

$("select").append(option);
$("select").trigger("change");
```

Note that I also triggered the `change` event so that Select2 can know that the selected options have changed.

Comment: Kevin, i have raised a question for select2. it seems like you have a good experience in it and you can solve the issue. I tried multiple times but its not working. If possible could you please look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729864/jquery-select2-selected-value-from-database-by-ajax

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I've needed!

Answer (score 11):

God I should stop to think before posting sometimes.

Its as simple as just adding a new option to the underlying select:

```
$("#myselect").append($('<option>', {value: 1, text: 'new option'}));
```

Don't even need to re-initialize the `select2`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with "Data" property of select2. Firstly, I got data with json and then I create my select2 element with my array as below.

corrCodeArray is my json array.

```
function fillSelectReportPeriod() {
var corrCodeArray = retrieveCorrCodes();
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 4,
    data: corrCodeArray
});
```

}

Note: When I give select2 element name like `$("#selectReportPeriod")` instead of `$(".js-example-basic-multiple")` it didn't work so I used class name.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
$("#company_dealer").val('Newly Selected Dealer').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question