# JQUERY Populate "Select" options dynamically based on input from another select element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I would like to change the options in a select element based on what i select in another select element (dropdown box).

I have two select boxes (RUNS and SAMPLES) on my PHP page. What i intend to do is to change options in the second select box based on a query that is performed against a database using the option selected in first select box.

I have a table in my database that connects "SAMPLES" to "RUNS". The first select box is populated by a set of 'RUNS' on page load. I would like the 'SAMPLES' that belong to the selected RUN to populate in the SAMPLES box.

The HTML would be something like

```
<select name='run_id' id='run_id>
    <option value='1'>RUN 1</option>
    <option value='2'>RUN 2</option>
    <option value='4'>RUN 3</option>
    <option value='5'>RUN 4</option>
</select>
```

The backend table "sample_runs" has columns run_id and sample_name. I have a PHP script as follows,

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","uname","pwwd");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$run_id = $_GET['run_id'];
$sql = "select distinct sample_name from samples where run_id = '$run_id'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)){
    echo '<option value='.$rs['sample_name'],'>'.$rs['sample_name']."</option>";
}
?>
```

I can modify the PHP script (easy part), but can someone share some code with me on how to populate the sample name options based on the run_id selected in the RUNS box.

Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: `mysql` methods are deprecated, and you are allowing raw input into your queries which is dangerous because it risks SQL injection.

Comment: Guess i should use PDO, but what is the workaround for the jquery part

Comment: You have a small typo in your HTML -- you forgot a `'`

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is small enough, you could send all of the data on page load.  Do this by building a JSON object that represents your entire dataset in PHP.  You can use PHP's json_encode function to do this:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Once you've built up a JSON string, you'll need to send it to some JavaScript to handle the population of the sample name options based on the selected run_id.  There's a good discussion on that here:  [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Finally, you'll need to write JavaScript to do the DOM manipulation necessary to change the contents of the second HTML select box.  Here's an example of that:  [Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript)

If your data set is too large to send in a single request, you'll need to build up a REST API to provide the data for each run when it is selected.

Good luck!!