# User is able to add option to dropdown list by typing it in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, web

Is there any HTML/JavaScript code that can allow the viewer of a webpage to add a option to a dropdown select list by typing it in a text box???

Comment: Yes, it's very simple to write such code if you know basic Javascript.

Comment: Use document.createElement('option') to create an option element and add to your select

Comment: I've hardly ever written ANY JavaScript as I've only just fully learned HTML and JavaScript @Barmar

Comment: @RicardoPontual I've hardly ever done JavaScript so would you be able to tell me how to do the full code, and how it links to HTML??

Comment: Do you want the solution to include jQuery or no?

Comment: @AdamCrookes SO is not a free code-writing service or a replacement for learning how to program. We're here to answer specific questions you have about the code you've written, not to do it for you.

Comment: Just google it and you'll find a lot of examples Adam.
Check this out, here there's a fiddle you can see html and javascript code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very basic example. No CSS, fancy formatting, error checking, anything. The value of the new option will be identical to the displayed string.

```js
function newOpt() {
  var $inp = $('#newOptIpt');
  var v = $inp.val();
  $('#modSelect').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
  $inp.val('')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="modSelect">
  <option value="default-1">Default option</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input id="newOptIpt"/>
<button onclick="newOpt();">Add Option</button>
```