# Generate HTML dynamically on button click in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box. I want to generate the same on a 'Add New' button click.

**View**

```
<button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn sbold green" ng-mousedown="count = count + 1" ng-click="Get_toolNames()">Add New
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>

<select class="bs-select form-control" name="tool_id" ng-model="Tooldata.tool_name" ng-options="t.tm_id as t.tm_name for t in tools" required>
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

How can I generate the same on this button click?

Comment: Read it, man! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
<button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn sbold green" ng-mousedown="count = count + 1" ng-click="buttonClick"> Add New
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
 </button>
```

In your `controller` you can inject and use `$compile` service.

```
$scope.buttonClick = function(){
   var el = angular.element(/* Here your element */);
   el.append( '<select class="bs-select form-control" name="tool_id" ng-model="Tooldata.tool_name"  ng-options="t.tm_id as t.tm_name for t in tools" required>' + 
                     '<option value="">Select</option>' + '</select>')
   $compile(el)($scope);
}
```

Change your logic to get the data and the element you want:

For more see [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

### Update

```
var sample_2_tbody = angular.element('#sample_2 tbody');
$compile(sample_2_tbody)($scope);
```

How to inject a service in the controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile){

}])
```

Comment: i have an error in console  $compile is not defined

Comment: @robins you must inject it in the `controller` function. Try the same way how you inject the `$scope`

Comment: ok..thanks for response.i'm new thats why i'm asking..how to set multiple value as selected in dropdown list

Comment: @robins add `selected` attribute to each item you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120586/discussion-between-robins-and-suren-srapyan).

Answer (score 0):

In *AngularJS* `views` are just a `model reflection` and their scope is only for *data presentation*. That's mean you never need to manually copy a DOM Element, you just need to operate on the bound model.

```js
function TestCtrl($scope, select) {
  copy = () => angular.copy(select);
  
  $scope.selects = [copy()];
  $scope.values = {};
  
  $scope.add = () => {
    //$scope.selects.unshift(select); // add at the beginning
    $scope.selects.push(copy()); // add at the end
  };
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .value('select', [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'aLabel',
    subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'bLabel',
    subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
  }])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'select',  TestCtrl])
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add($event)">Add</button>
    <hr>
    
    <div ng-repeat="select in selects track by $index">

      <select ng-model="values[$index]" ng-options="t as t.label for t in select">
      </select>
    
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <pre><code ng-bind="values | json"></code></pre>
  </article>
</section>
```