# jquery how to fill select option in my form

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Rbz.png)
The json (data) looks like this
guys! I have a little form. Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ajaxform">
<input type="text" size="32" maxlength="36" name="name" placeholder="Вaшe имя" val="">
        <select id="activity_2" name="activity_2">
        <option value="">Exmaple</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="GO GO GO"/>
</form>
<script src="/add-information/aa.js"></script>
```

In this little code i receive a json with data from my database:

```
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data);
```

in data there is id and name of the rubric. How can i load all this array in my option list?
I was told to do something like this:

```
var select = document.getelementById('activity_2'); // id of the select 
select.options[i] = new Option(data.id, data.od); // add data?
```

help me please, how i can fill select with data from 'data'?

THE SOLUTION BY ADEON IS:

var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(data);

```
    var select = document.getElementById('activity_2');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    select.options[select.length] = new Option(data.data[i].name_rus, data.data[i].id);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript)

Comment: Didn't the suggestion you posted work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do these:
1) Your call `getelementById` should be changed to `getElementById` otherwise you would receive error.
2) You need to create options string first and then append that string to DOM rather than touching DOM every time you add options. Touching DOM as less as possible is a good idea from performance point of view.
3) To simplify the syntax you can use string interpolation syntax like below:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('activity_2');
//$(select).html('');
var data = [{id:1, name_rom:'a', name_rus:'abc'},{id:2, name_rom:'x', name_rus:'xyz'}];
var options = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  options += `<option value=${data[i].id}>${data[i].name_rus}</option>`;//<--string 
                                                             //interpolation
}
$(select).append(options);
//OR below, so you don't need to call document.getElementById
//$('#activity_2').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="ajaxform">
  <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="36" name="name" placeholder="Вaшe имя" val="">
  <select id="activity_2" name="activity_2">
        <option value="">Exmaple</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: your example works, but when i try to insert my var data - it doesn't works. I edit my post, there is a image, where you can see how my data array looks like. Can you edit your code, please?

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий What do you want in options out of `id`, `name_rom`, `name_rus`? Do you want just `id`?

Comment: Dear Shukla, i want to fill in select value = id and it will be named = name_rus

Comment: Like this:
<option value="id"> name_rus</option>

Comment: See my edit. I have added value as id=1,2 and text, as name_rus=abc,xyz respectively for two options. Hopefully this is what you are looking for!

Comment: I am sorry, but when a try to add my data var - it doesn't work. I don't understand, why

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? What errors?

Comment: Can i meet you in skype or facebook? Sorry, if i disturb you.

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий Still I am not clear. do you see any errors in console.log window (assuming chrome)?

Comment: Nope. No errors. Just new options don't appear. This is image of my code:
https://i.gyazo.com/45b7cbfdc15372d3690164b2d91e7a2a.png
And this is output. Only an object in console and that;s all:
https://i.gyazo.com/36e690a47066e2d9670a32ee4a78b797.png

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий Try to use this `options += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name_rus + '</option>';`

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий What is the version of chrome? Also, you can change the last line to `$('#activity_2').append(options);` This would save you from calling getElementById.

Comment: added, didn't helped.
Chrome is the last(

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий OK, just try putting my code without ajax call for experiments?

Comment: with your var data evertything works fine! But only i use my data json - nothing happens. :(

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий Also console.log(options); What do you get?

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий With your data?

Comment: chrome - https://i.gyazo.com/24b493920d5f1412a263fb3c7f926ed2.png
console log displays nothing.
code - https://i.gyazo.com/859047d890d1a619e9532cb4968897e3.png

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий Last try! Do the same but use options as `options += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name_rus + '</option>';`

Comment: result - https://i.gyazo.com/5c15ad93c2dd900254ef7d2d4539b011.png

code - https://i.gyazo.com/cfd20df794716cf4c28b70a27a51d5d6.png

Comment: @СтаниславСтроянецкий Did you debug? Do you go inside for loop?

Comment: i like your solution the most, I will set your solution as answer. i will go and test it. if you have some ideas, message me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your `data` and append option html to your `select`.

```
var select = document.getelementById('activity_2');
$(select).html('');
for (var i in data) {
    $(select).append('<option value=' + data[i] + '>' + data[i] + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is an array, you could iterate over it and apply it to the DOM like so.

```
var optionString = '';
var data = ['John', 'Josh'];

data.forEach(function(dataItem, index){
  optionString += '<option value="' + index + '">' + dataItem + '</option>';
});

$('#activity_2').append(optionString);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9ke5fzqo/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `add` method which accepts as parameter a new `Option`.

The constructor of `Option` looks like this: `new Option(text,value)`.

```js
var array=[{
            "text":"text1",
            "value":"value1"
          },{
            "text":"text2",
            "value":"value2"
          }];
var select = document.getElementById('activity_2');
array.forEach(function(item){
  select.add(new Option(item.text,item.value));
});
```

```html
<select id="activity_2" name="activity_2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.append in jquery to add new option into a select input.
Html:

```
<select id="selinput" name="activity_2"> <option value="">Exmaple</option> </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#selinput").append('<option value="1">value</option>');
```

Or you can use [jquery.selec2](https://select2.github.io) plugin.