# How can I add an html option element dynamically to a select?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I dynamically add the option elements to the select using a for loop?

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I have tried various forms of innerHTML but no luck.

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before. And why do you need a for-loop? Be more specific. [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: you didn't post the loop you mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Adding options to select from an array?

html

```
<select name="select" id="select"></select>
```

javascript

```
var myOptions = ['one','two','three'];
var select = document.getElementById('select');
for (var i = 1; i <= myOptions.length; i++) {
    var option = '<option value="'+ i + '" >' + myOptions[i-1] + '</option>';
    select.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', option );
}
```

Comment: This works well for me. Guess I did not dig deep enough into html documentation to come across insertAdjacentHTML.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You can modify the code to fit in a loop and add your dynamic options.

```js
var selectInnerHTML = document.getElementById('dynamic-select').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('dynamic-select').innerHTML = selectInnerHTML + '<option value="4">Four</option>';
```

```html
<select id="dynamic-select" class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```