# How can I target an element, held within a template, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-travel-itinerary-items">
    <div class="panel-wrap panel-wrap-itinerary">
        <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Etape', 'wp-travel' ); ?></label>
        <select id="selectjs"></select>
     </div>
</script>
```

`getElementById()` on *`selectjs`* is `null`; ow can I target this element, via its id, within a script tag?

Comment: Can you please post your js code?

Comment: It makes no sense to wrap html tags in `<script>` tags. It could even be the cause of your problem. Remove the `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Peter I suppose it is a template which is later used by some js code.

Comment: The js code is merely a test `document.getElementById('selectjs').innerHTML="<option>lorem ipsum</option>";`

And for the reason of HTML wrapped inside a <script> is to display several "options" if the user choose to click (in this case) **Add itinerary**.

Comment: Order of calling is not clear. Maybe you call `getElementById` before required element appears in DOM.

Comment: If this is a template you should denote the script stags as such using ` type = “text/template”`; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912586/explanation-of-script-type-text-template-script

Comment: In order to test the order of calling, I've put a dummy <div> outside the <script> and it worked. The problem, I think, is that the HTML content is not visible until I Add an itinerary so I can't access it with getElementById().

Comment: It seems you're trying to achieve this end result: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgsufqet/), when this approach may be easier: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgsufqet/1/)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: apart from the poorly-phrased title, I don't believe this question is answered by your proposed duplicate. The question here seems to be: "*how can I access an element held within a template?*" and bears no relevance to the question in the title.

Comment: Thanks for the more relevant title. @DavidThomas Thanks for the example, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to — ultimately — retrieve the element via its `id` property using the `<script>` template approach; however it is convoluted, and requires - so far as I can tell - the creation of a temporary element to hold the template content and then querying that element:

```js
// retrieve the innerHTML of the template, using the id of the template itself:
let templateSource = document.getElementById('tmpl-wp-travel-itinerary-items').innerHTML,

// creating an element to hold, and from which to retrieve, that content:
    template = document.createElement('div');

// assigning the content of the template as the innerHTML of the created-element:
template.innerHTML = templateSource;

// finally, retrieving the <select> element via its id, from the
// created-element and Element.querySelector():
let selectElement = template.querySelector('#selectjs');

// logging the selectElement to the console:
console.log(selectElement);
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-wp-travel-itinerary-items">
  <div class="panel-wrap panel-wrap-itinerary">
    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Etape', 'wp-travel' ); ?></label>
    <select id="selectjs"></select>
  </div>
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgsufqet/).

There is, however, a slightly easier approach, using the HTML `<template>` element:

```js
// retrieving the <template> via its id:
let template = document.querySelector('#templateContent'),

  // accessing the <select> from the content property
  // of the <template>:
  select = template.content.querySelector('select');

// logging the <select> element to the console:
console.log(select);
```

```html
<template id="templateContent">
  <div class="panel-wrap panel-wrap-itinerary">
    <label></label>
    <select id="selectjs"></select>
  </div>
</template>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pgsufqet/1/)

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
- [`HTMLTemplateElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement).
- [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: As I don't want to modify the existing code, I've choose to run with your first answer as it is the most relevant to my problem. The console log returned `<select id="selectjs">` but how do you suggest to add an option ?

Comment: Once you have a reference to the `<select>` element then the proposed duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript) becomes relevant. Disclaimer: I also wrote the accepted answer on that question.