# What's the javascript equivalent of $("<option>", { value: "thing1", text: "thing2" }));

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
retVal.push($("<option>", { value: "thing1", text: "thing2" }));
```

I know it returns a `JQuery<HTMLElement>` object but I'm not sure of an elegant way of doing this that doesn't involve string concatenation.

For reference, I'm iterating over an object of KeyValuePairs and dynamically building a collection of options for a select html element.

Edit: full current code

```
ctl.append(ConvertStatusToDropdownItems());
...
var StatusEnum = { "thing1": 0, "thing2": 1, etc. };

function ConvertStatusToDropdownItems() {
var retVal = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(StatusEnum)) {
    retVal.push($("<option>", { value: value, text: key }));
}
return retVal;
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm technically inside a Typescript file in a .Net Core 2.1 site and can't seem to get the definitions for JQuery to load. And on further reflection, it's probably not a good idea to do so given the global nature of this function.

Comment: using createElement? or new Option()

Comment: using .append. Just need to do it without jquery. See edit for full "enough" code.

Comment: so appendChild()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript

Comment: See edit for why that link might not work. I am still reading though so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript we can create a helper function that assists us in replicating the functionality of the JQuery method.

```
let create = (tag, opts = {}) => {
  return Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), opts); 
}
```

```js
let create = (tag, opts = {}) => {
  return Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), opts); 
}

console.log( 
  create("option", { value: "thing1", textContent: "thing2"})  
);
```

**Note** There is no such thing as a `text` property on a normal DOM node, only `textContent`.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for. Short and elegant.