# Error when trying to populate a drop-down box with a javascript array generated by a REST API call

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a page with a hidden drop-down box that appears when a checkbox is ticked via a JavaScript `inner.HTML =` command.  As I'm aware I wouldn't be able to populate this from a `document.onload` function, I've got a `<div>`, that I'll be setting to `style="display:none"` when I have this working, where I have a drop-down box in for the options to be populated to, however I'm getting the error message `'Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference'` when attempting to do this.  Is a `<select>` tag not able to have an ID or `innerHTML` value given to it?

Code is below:

```
var systemOptions = [];
var system = document.getElementById("systemstemp");
document.onload = getSystems();

function getSystems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: ".../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Application List')/items?$select=Title",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {
      systemOptions = data.d.results;
      for (var obj in systemOptions) {
        system.innerHTML = "<option value='" + systemOptions[obj].Title + "'>" + systemOptions[obj].Title + "</option>";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<p><select id="systemstemp"></select></p>
```

```
systemOptions = [
  {Title: "Call Platform"},
  {Title: "CRM"},
  {Title: "Email"},
  {Title: "Monitoring"},
]
```

Comment: You can see the solution here. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
document.onload = getSystems();
```

you're actually calling `getSystems` function immediately and not when `document.onload` fires. In order to run `getSystems` when `onload` triggers, set the function without parenthesis:

```
document.onload = getSystems;
```

or assign the function directly to the `document.onload`:

```
document.onload = function() {
  $.ajax({...});
}
```

**EDIT**

You should also use DOM API to create the select options like in this Q/A:

[Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript)