# My json api fetch seems not to work, what should I use with data?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I cannot seem to get the categories(planets,dwarfplanets and other) inside the dropdown menu. I know I should use data.*something* but idk what, any help?

**HTML**

```
<select id="categories"></select>
```

**The link to my json api**
`[https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-ee-solar-system-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/data.json][1]`

**For my javascript I have this**

```
"use strict"

window.addEventListener("load", Init);

var categories;

function Init()
{
    categories = document.getElementById("categories");

    FetchData();
}


function FetchData(){
fetch("https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-ee-solar-system-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/data.json")  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = data[i].name;
          categories.add(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. To get all the different types out of your data object you could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then replace `data` in your loop with `data[type]`.

Instead of `add` you need to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add elements into another DOM node.

```js
"use strict"

window.addEventListener("load", Init);

var categories;

function Init()
{
    categories = document.getElementById("categories");

    FetchData();
}


function FetchData(){
fetch("https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-ee-solar-system-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/data.json")  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
        
        const types = Object.keys(data);
        
        for(const type of types) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data[type].length; i++) {
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = data[type][i].name;
            categories.appendChild(option);
          }
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="categories"></select>
```

**EDIT: Categories instead of planet names**

```js
"use strict"

window.addEventListener("load", Init);

var categories;

function Init()
{
    categories = document.getElementById("categories");

    FetchData();
}


function FetchData(){
fetch("https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-ee-solar-system-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/data.json")  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
        
        const types = Object.keys(data);
        
        for(const type of types) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = type;
          categories.appendChild(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="categories"></select>
```

Comment: This looks good, but I am still wondering how to get the 3 "categories: eg:(planets,dwarfplanets and other) inside the select

Comment: @OfficialRules as you can see the `Object.keys` return the name of the categories. You could use that and append them like i did with the planet names.

Comment: @OfficialRules I created a quick edit (second snippet) to show you what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are assuming data is an array, but it is actually an object. You can't do Object.length on an object to iterate over it

Instead, you could use the for...in statement to iterate over an object.

```
response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
            
        for (const category in data) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = category;
          
          categories.appendChild(option);
        }    
      });
```

As the other answer said, you were very close!

Comment: hmm I see, thank you all this realy helped!

Answer (score 0):

The api call's response is not an array, it's an object.

```js
"use strict"

window.addEventListener("load", Init);

var categories;

function Init()
{
    categories = document.getElementById("categories");

    FetchData();
}


function FetchData(){
fetch("https://howest-gp-wfa.github.io/st-2021-1-S2-ee-solar-system-Jonas-Bundervoet/api/data.json")  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
        const types = Object.keys(data);
          
        types.forEach(type => {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = type;
          categories.add(option);
        });
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
}
```