# innerHTML not working for select tag when i want to change new options

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, innerhtml

html code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="domain" class="form-control show-tick" onchange="myFunction1()">
        {% for item in domains %}
        <option value=" {{item.0}} ">{{item.1}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="2">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js function:

```
<script>
  function myFunction1() {
    x = document.getElementById("domain").value;
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML += "<OPTION>1</OPTION>";
    alert(x);
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to change the drop-down box with id set as 2 when an on-change function is called in other drop-down box. Code looks good but i cant see the new options added.

Comment: should the `+=` after the `innerHTML` on the script be there?

Comment: Add a tag for whatever library you're using (`{%%}`) and search for how to add a new option. I'm sure it's been answered. It might be different with the library you're using though.

Comment: yes, since I am trying to add new options as the user keep on selecting new domains.

Comment: I am using {%%} because i am working with django and using them to populate mydropdown list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript

Comment: Please add Python & Django tags so folks know what you're asking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding options to select with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript)

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't work ? Because i tested its working fine . Please check your browser console if there are any error