# Auto populate select box using Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a select box:

```
<select id="translationOptions" name="translationOptions"></select>
```

And I have a js array

```
var translationOptions = ["Egyptian Hieroglyphs", "Al Bhed (Final Fantasy X)", "Futurama"];
```

How would I auto populate the select box based on the `var translationOptions`?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.each(translationOptions, function(key, value) {   
    $('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
});
```

[What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Comment: How could you pull the data from a couple of `INPUT` fields into the array to then feed into the above? I tried `var translationOptions = ['$("input[name="inputboxname"]").val()'];` but it just returns `['$("input[name="inputboxname"]").val()']` as the SELECT option

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(translationOptions, function(index, value) {
    $('#translationOptions').append($("<option />").val(index).text(value));
});
```

This uses text for display and index in the array for value.

Answer (score 2):

You can create options dynamically and append to select box in this way as well.

```
jQuery.each(translationOptions, function(key, value) {
    jQuery('<option/>', {
       'value': key,
       'text' : value
}).appendTo('#translationOptions');
```