# Copy from select option to dynamic select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

How can I get all the options of a select created dynamicly get from option from first,
i try with jquery but didnt work:

```
 for( j = 0; j < i; j++)
     $('#s1 option').clone().appendTo(IS+j);
```

**HTML file:**

```
<input type="button" value="Add" id="btn1" OnClick="f('dv1');">
<div id="dv1">
    <select id="s1" name="select1">
        <option>
            1
        </option>

        <option>
            2
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

***functions.js***

```
var i = 1;
function f(x){
    var y = document.createElement('div');
    y.innerHTML = '<br><Select id="IS"'+i+ 'name="NAME"'+i+' > </Select>';
    document.getElementById(x).appendChild(y);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: $('#s1 option').clone().appendTo('NAME'+j);
or
 $('#s1 option').clone().appendTo((#+'IS'+j));
didnt work too.

Comment: make sure you added the <select id="IS"> first before adding the copy of <options>

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are creating multiple select objects, you need to fix your jquery selector and the id that you are generating for the selects. First of all, `$('#s1 option').clone().appendTo(IS+j);`
should be changed to:

```
$('#s1 option').clone().appendTo('#IS' + j);
```

Secondly, `y.innerHTML = '<br><Select id="IS"'+i+ 'name="NAME"'+i+' > </Select>';`
should be changed to:

```
y.innerHTML = '<br /><select id="IS'+i+ '" name="NAME'+i+'"></select>';
```

**Edit**:

If you are just trying to clone your original dropdown, the following should work for you:

```
function f(x){
    // Create new select within its own div
    var y = document.createElement('div');
    y.innerHTML = '<br /><select id="IS'+i+ '" name="NAME'+i+'"></select>';
    document.getElementById(x).appendChild(y);

    // Fill new select with the options from the original
    $('#IS' + i).html($('#s1').html());

    i++;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/myGgx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way if you need to iterate through the options for whatever reason to perhaps make a change

```
var newSelect = $("<select />");

$.each(primarySelect.options, function (i, opt)
{
   $(newSelect).append($('<option></option>', { 
       value: opt.value, text: opt.text, selected: opt.selected }));
});
```

[JS Fiddle Live Version](http://jsfiddle.net/tpFc7/3/)

Be sure not to use `$(primarySelect.options).each(...)` because that won't work in IE propertly.

---

See also: [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)