# jQuery IE9 repopulating select options with ajax

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

The following code works perfectly in non-IE browsers.  **Please note that these first three options were added via jQuery.**

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="1">MyVal1</option>
  <option value="2">MyVal2</option>
  <option value="3">MyVal3</option>
</select>
```

I clear out the options so I can add new ones:

```
// my new values has the proper values of [{"Id": 4, "Text" : "MyVal4"}, {"Id": 5, "Text": "MyVal5"}]
$("#mySelect").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < myNewVals.length; i++) {            
  $("#mySelect").append('<option value="' + myNewVals[i].Id + '">' + myNewVals[i].Text + '</option');
}
```

It works the first time I try to populate it, but then every subsequent time thereafter, it repopulates the dropdown with the same values.  Why does it ignore the new values when attempting to remake the options?

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: Your json array doesn't look right

Comment: For some reason the list of options is retained ONLY in IE.  I cannot figure out why!

Comment: The array is just a sample of the data, it's not proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a JSON array, try something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myNewVals = { 4: 'Myval4', 5: 'Myval5' };

        $("#popButton").bind('click', function (event) {

            $("#mySelect").empty(); 
            $.each(myNewVals, function(val, text) {
                $("#mySelect").append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text))
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">MyVal1</option>
    <option value="2">MyVal2</option>
    <option value="3">MyVal3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="popButton" value="Populate!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because I was attempting to remove the disabled attribute from the dropdown.  If I disable it in between repopulations, it seems to work.  Very stupid bug.