# using jquery with this and html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

In the following code .tg is a class  tag. I get the alert as `got here` but i d o not see this happen `this.html(opt_arr[i]);` how to resolve this issue

```
  function populate_combo()
  {
     var opt_arr=new Array();

     var tg_len = $('.tg').length;
     arr_len = '{{response_dict.opt_arr_len}}';
     if(arr_len == tg_len)
     {
        alert("got here")
        {% for htm in response_dict.opt_arr %}
           opt_arr.push('{{htm}}') 
        {% endfor %}
        $(".tg").each(function (i) {
        this.html(opt_arr[i]);
           });

     }
     else
     {
        alert("There was an error while loadind dropdown box data");
     }

  }
```

`EDIT`

```
   {% for td in response_dict.taggeddata %}
     <tr id="{{td.id}}">
     <td width="20%">{{td.field1}}</td>
      {% if response_dict.tag_flag == 1 %}
              <td class="tg"></td>
     {% endif %}
        </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: +1 for using `alert ("got here")`

Comment: What's the value of `tg_len`? If it's 0 then obviously the `each` loop will have nothing to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$(this)` instead of `this` to convert it to jquery object, and use jquery function on it..

```
$(this).html(opt_arr[i]);
```

[Not Working](http://jsfiddle.net/qwSus)

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/qwSus/1/)

Comment: but actually the dropdown box doesnt appear i can see the html code

Comment: I presume u are trying to insert options from the `for` loop..changing html is not the way to do it..

Comment: but usually when u say $.html() will sonvert to html right.If not how to go about it in this case

Comment: give complete code..what is `.tg`..do u have select box already..btw u are removing all html of `.tg` initially..read this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: I have edited the question and have given the html also have removed $('.tg').html(''); thats not required

Comment: Thanks got it working that was not an issue with the JS you had told

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tg").each(function (i, e) {
    e.innerHTML = opt_arr[i];
});
```