# How to add select menu options to multiple selects using javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have code that iterates through a loop and then adds that option to a select. What I would like to do is populate a list of select menu options and then take that list and then add it to multiple select menus. Here is the code I currently have:

```
var SelectDropDown = document.getElementById("forgetuniversity");
$("#forgetuniversity").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < ArrayUniversisities.length ; i++) 
{
    var university = data[i];
    var NewOption = new Option(university.Name , university.UniversityID);
    SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
    SelectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
};
```

I'd want `NewOption` to have the whole list contained in it and for me to simply have `Select1.add(NewOption)`, `Select2.add(NewOption)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this [See Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

**For Array**

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
$('#mySelect').append($("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
}));
```

});

**For List**

**JQuery**

```
var list = $("#selectList");
$.each(items, function(index, item) {
list.append(new Option(item.text, item.value));
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
var list = document.getElementById("selectList");
for(var i in items) {
list.add(new Option(items[i].text, items[i].value));
}
```