# How can i get this Json to Fill my dropdown in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

The Goal is User types inputs an id the id get processed using StringFormat. Then compared to the database the return result returns all matches.  So I have it returned in a JSON. I want to pull out the First and Last name and fill the Dropdown with it that infomation

This is my viewmodel
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

```
namespace eFilingNoticeRetrieval.Models
{
    public class efViewModel
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string efdcp_Random { get; set; }
    public int fk_efd_ID { get; set; } 


    }
}
```

This is My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Details(string searchTerm)
    {
        string searchTerm1 = StringFormat(searchTerm); // Takes the random off

        var model =
            from e in _db.eFiling_Document_CourtProcessed
            join item in _db.eQueue_Party on e.fk_efd_ID equals item.fk_efd_ID
            where (e.efdcp_UniqueServiceID == searchTerm1)
            select new efViewModel
            {
                first_name = item.efp_FirstName,
                last_name = item.efp_LastName,
                efdcp_Random = e.efdcp_Random,
                fk_efd_ID = item.fk_efd_ID
            };
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.ToList());

            return result;
    }
```

This is my view

```
<input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" onchange="getting()" />


<select  id="drops"/>

function getting()
{

    var searchTerm = $('#searchTerm').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
          data: { searchTerm: searchTerm },

           beforeSend: function () { },
           success: function (searchTerm)
            {
               $($.parseJSON(searchTerm)).map(function () {
                   return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
               }).appendTo('#drops');

            }

        });
```

This is my return

```
"[{\"first_name\":\"JIM\",\"last_name\":\"JOHNSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"BQONIZ\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771},{\"first_name\":\"JIM\",\"last_name\":\"JOHNSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"ELWKHE\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771},{\"first_name\":\"JIM\",\"last_name\":\"JOHNSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"ARVYTN\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771},{\"first_name\":\"NICK\",\"last_name\":\"NICHOLSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"BQONIZ\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771},{\"first_name\":\"NICK\",\"last_name\":\"NICHOLSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"ELWKHE\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771},{\"first_name\":\"NICK\",\"last_name\":\"NICHOLSON\",\"efdcp_Random\":\"ARVYTN\",\"fk_efd_ID\":771}]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re factor this a bit

for your controller instead of

```
JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
result.Data=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.ToList());
```

try

```
return Json(model.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

for your jquery try

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Home")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { searchTerm: searchTerm },
            beforeSend: function () { },
            success: function (searchTerm) {
                if (searchTerm) {
                    var $drops = $('#drops');
                    for (var i = 0; i < searchTerm.length; i++) {
                        $drops.append($('<option value="'+searchTerm[i].fk_efd_ID +'">'+searchTerm[i].first_name + " " + searchTerm[i].last_name +'</option>'));
                    }
                }                  
            }
        });
```

**Edit**

this is much more clean [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { searchTerm: searchTerm },
        beforeSend: function () { },
        success: function (searchTerm) {
            if (searchTerm) {
                $.each(searchTerm, function (key, value) {
                    $('#drops')
                         .append($('<option>', { value: value.fk_efd_ID })
                         .text(first_name + " " + last_name));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if this was right please mark my answer as the correct answer :)