# html5 form drop down menu, with menu items in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have this form set up as a basic drop down menu that goes to whichever link / option is selected immediately, but I was wondering if it was possible / how to append all of the options in JavaScript in a separate file? I am just starting to learn JavaScript, so any explanation would be exceptionally helpful too. Thank you for your time!

```
<form name="nav">
    <select name="navigation" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO" style="width:100%;">
        <option selected="selected">go to...</option>
        <option value="index.html">PROJECTS</option>
        <option value="about.html">ABOUT</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a demo to start with](http://jsbin.com/EGezOyuG/1/edit)

The HTML

```
<form id="my-form">
  <select name="navigation">
    <option>Go to...</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Now we just encode the navigation options in a JSON object and dynamically load them into the `select` element

```
var navigation = [
  {"title": "PROJECTS", url: "index.html"},
  {"title": "ABOUT", url: "about.html"}
];

var select = document.getElementById("my-form").navigation;

for (var i=0, option; i<navigation.length; i++) {
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = navigation[i].url;
  option.innerText = navigation[i].title;
  select.appendChild(option);
}

select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  window.location.href = select.value;
});
```

This is vanilla JavaScript, but you could use jQuery if you like that better.

Comment: This is working really well for me and does exactly what I need. The only issue is that it doesn't append the options in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I dont how much You know JS or which framework (server, client) You are using. But regardless of that You could for example try to built navigation here using content sent from the server.

For instance You generate the request in the client side, that You want to load navigation dynamically into this select and on a success ajax You populate the dropdown.

Write more about the frameworks You are using. Is the JS pure JS or perhaps jQuery.

BTW. The code You've posted isn't exactly HTML5-way of building the dropdown. 
Go to [HTML5 Form elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_elements.asp) and take a look on the very first example with

```
<input list="browsers">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var str = '<option selected="selected">go to...</option>'+
          '<option value="index.html">PROJECTS</option>'+
          '<option value="about.html">ABOUT</option>';
$('#formId').html("");
$('#formId').append(str);
```

Hope this helps.