# Why does using jQuery's .append() function with a jQuery object with an element name and an array in it as the single parameter work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, jquery-append

I have a question about how jQuery's .append function works in the following segment of code that dynamically adds values to a select box:

```
for (var i=currentYear; i >= minYear; i--){
    $('#year').append($("<option/>", { value: i, text: i}));
}
```

I already know that this code does work, as I've used .append in this way before after finding similar code online during a google search. However, the webpage I found the similar code on (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3155663/3120918) did not explain why it works. I ready the official jQuery documentation page on the .append function (http://api.jquery.com/append/), but it did not say anything about passing in a single jQuery object containing both a self-closed option element and an array ( `$("<option/>", {value: key, text: value })` ) as the single parameter to the append function. I was hoping that someone could explain to me how and why this works.

Comment: I don't see any array in your example code

Comment: [Here is the relevant section of the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) Also that's not an array, it's just an object. Arrays have square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

> jQuery object containing both a self-closed option element and an array ( `$("<option/>", {value: key, text: value })` )

Nah, that is a special form of the [jQuery constructor for "creating elements"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to `$()`, jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML [*and if it does*], jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.
>
> […]
>
> The second argument to `jQuery()` can accept a plain object consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the `.attr()` method.
>
> **Important**: If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the first argument must represent a a simple element with no attributes. As of jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height`, or `offset`.
>
> […]

So what does happen here is the construction of a new `<option>` element with given value and text, which is wrapped in a jQuery collection. This is then passed to [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which (as usual) appends all elements from the collection to its elements - in here, the new option to your `#year` `<select>` element.