# How to append options when click first time on select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-select

How to append options when click first time on select tag? That mean select tag have no option until click it first time. I try code as below but the options not show until click second time, I want the options show immediately at the first time i click select tag. Please help me.

```
<select id="cbVoice" onclick="ClickMe()"></select>

function ClickMe(){
if($('#cbVoice > option').length == 0){ 
var TheOptions = "<option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option>";
        $('#cbVoice').html(TheOptions);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mousedown` with `one()`, and a simple loop for the `options`:

```
$('#cbVoice').one('mousedown', function() {
   var numOfOpts = 4, opts = [];
   for (var i = 1; i <= numOfOpts; i++) {
       opts.push( $('<option>', { text: 'Option ' + i }) );
   }
   $(this).append(opts);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLb7s/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function ClickMe(){
if($('#cbVoice > option').length == 0){ 
var TheOptions = "<option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option>";
        $('#cbVoice').empty().append(TheOptions);
}

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8a8rj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
     $('#mySelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
});
```

Duplicate of [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="cbVoice"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $cbVoice = $("#cbVoice");
$cbVoice.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if ($('option', $cbVoice).length == 0) {
        $cbVoice.html('<option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option><option>Option 4</option>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eeSGN/