# Appending this specific array to html select with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

I have the following script:

```
$(function () {
    var selectValues = new Array();
    selectValues = [{"Selected":false,"Text":"Apple","Value":"1"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Samsung","Value":"2"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"LG","Value":"3"}];
    $.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
        $('#brand-0')
             .append($('<option>', { value: key })
             .text(value))
             .prop("selectedIndex", -1);
    });
    });
```

But when it runs, it displays each list object as [object Object]. What am I missing?

Comment: You have an Array of Objects, so the `value` is the whole object. You need to choose which keys/values from the objects you actually need. I assume you want `.Text` for `.text()`, and `.Value` for `value`.

Comment: u need to use two for loops.

Comment: ...also, you can eliminate the `.text()` and `.prop()` calls, and just set all the data in the second argument to the element creation.

Comment: the prop call is necessary for a different reason. I'm not sure how to rewrite this so that it works with the Objects

Comment: You can check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted above, you have an array of objects, so each `value` in the `.each()` loop is the current object. You need to extract the data appropriate for each placement in the new `option` element.

```
$(function () {
    var selectValues = [{"Selected":false, "Text":"Apple",  "Value":"1"},
                        {"Selected":false, "Text":"Samsung","Value":"2"},
                        {"Selected":false, "Text":"LG",     "Value":"3"}];
    var brand = $('#brand-0');

    brand[0].selectedIndex = -1;

    $.each(selectValues, function (i, value) {
        $('<option>', { 
             value: value.Value,
             text: value.Text
        }).appendTo(brand);

        if (value.Selected) {
            brand[0].selectedIndex = i;
        }
    });
});
```

---

And by the way, you don't need all those double quotes in the `selectedValues` objects.

```
var selectValues = [{Selected:false, Text:"Apple",  Value:"1"},
                    {Selected:false, Text:"Samsung",Value:"2"},
                    {Selected:false, Text:"LG",     Value:"3"}];
```

Comment: Yea the array is pulled from an MVC ViewBag of SelectList elements, can't help the quotes :P

Answer (score 1):

In your `each` loop, the parameter `value` contains one element of you array : `{"Selected":false,"Text":"Apple","Value":"1"}` for example.

Your need to specify which key of you object you want to display, otherwise you will display the whole object, which shows `[object Object]`

```
$(function () {
    var selectValues = new Array();
    selectValues = [{"Selected":false,"Text":"Apple","Value":"1"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"Samsung","Value":"2"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"LG","Value":"3"}];
    $.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
    $('#brand-0')
        .append($('<option>', { value: value.key })
        .text(value.text))
        .prop("selectedIndex", -1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling object should be like this

```
$.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
        $('#brand-0')
             .append($('<option>', { value:value.Value })
             .text(value.Text))
             .prop("selectedIndex", value.SelectedIndex);
    });
```

use example demo:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7EWJj/)