# Add new item in a select tag and refresh it without refreshing the whole page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I refresh a select tag after adding new item into it using Jquery.

HTML :

```
    <select id="exam_select" class="exam_select" name="exam_select" value="Select Exam">
        <option value="">Select Exam</option>
        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($exam)):
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['e_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['e_code'];?></option>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="add_new_deg_field" class="hide_show" placeholder="New Exam Name"/> 
    <button id="add_edu_deg" class="hide_show">Add</button> <p id="save_exam" class="hide_show p_hide_show"></p>
```

JQuery :

```
         $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'exam_entry.php',
                    data: 'add_new_deg_field='+ $('#add_new_deg_field').val(),                           
                    success: function(reply_data){
                        $('#save_exam').html(reply_data);


                    }
                });

                return false;
        }
```

By this code I can save new item in my database table by clicking 'add_edu_deg' button. But can't refresh the select tag options. How can I do it using jquery. I search a lot but can't find any solution. Plz help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to remove the selected `<option>` once it has been selected since you haven't defined what you mean by `refresh`

If that is the case ,  within the success callback you can do:

```
 $('#exam_select option:selected').remove();
```

If this is not your intent, the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option to a select input with append.

```
<select><option>Option 1</option></select>
<button>Add option</button>

var x = 2;
$("button").click(function(){
    $("select").append("<option>Option "+x+"</option>");
    x++;
});
```

If you somehow save your option to x with ajax (I don't know how, never used ajax before), then execute append on your select, it will be added to the list without needing to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ka5Y/

```
$('#addOption').on('click',addOption);
var i = 0;
function addOption(){ 
     $('#mooSelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",i++)
         .text("Option " + i)); 
}
```

which is pretty much what is in the question

[What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)