# populate dropdown with json response data for currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have json data, i want to populate this values into select-box..
I tried([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5czG4/73/)) below code but its NOT populating drop-down, please help me.

```
var obj= 
     {
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram", 
    "XOF": "CFA Franc BCEAO",
    "XPF": "CFP Franc",
    "YER": "Yemeni Rial",
    "ZAR": "South African Rand",
    "ZMK": "Zambian Kwacha (pre-2013)",
    "ZMW": "Zambian Kwacha",
    "ZWL": "Zimbabwean Dollar"

};

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj.[i]);
  $('select').append(option);

}
```

html

`<select></select>`

Comment: Your object is not an array, and therefore cannot be used with an indexer.  Have you tried using a for each loop?

Comment: Please don't forget to select one as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var o in obj) {
    var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj[o]);
    $('select').append(option);
}
```

You might want values for each option too:

```
for (var o in obj) {
    var option=$('<option></option>').val(o).text(obj[o]);
    $('select').append(option);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5czG4/77/

Answer (score 2):

There's no dot in `obj[i]`.

And since you're using jQuery you can do:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value){
    $select.append( $("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option") );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Object members cannot be accessed with numeric subscripts (unless their keys happen to be numbers); you must use their keys instead. There is a very simple syntax for iterating through an object's keys:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj[key]);
    $('select').append(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers will work, as mentioned, you are trying to access an object as though it were an array. here is mine:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
{
    var option= $('<option value="' + keys[i] + '">' + obj[keys[i]] + '</option>');
    $('select').append(option);
}
```

on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5czG4/75/