# Appending options to select element doesn't work - MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I want to update a select options according to date that the user picks. For that I tried using ajax request to get data and append the data received to a  select element as options. There's nothing wrong with the json object that's received as I tried logging data to console and it gives the data I ant. But hen I try to append it to select element the options do not get appended.

JavaScript code

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'sessions',
                data: { date: date },
                success: function (data) {
                    var sessions = data['sessions'];
                    console.log(sessions);
                    $('select').html('');
                    $.each(sessions, function (i, session) {                            
                        $('select').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: session[0],
                            text : session[1]
                        }));
                        console.log(i);
                        console.log(session[1]);
                    });
                   }
                });
```

html code

```
    <div class="row">
 <div id="sessionDiv" class="input-field"  style="padding:10px">
    <select class="black-text text-lighten-1" name="session" id="session" >
        <option  value="0" disabled selected>Choose your preferred session</option>
    </select>
    <label for="session" class="purple-text text-lighten-2"> Session :</label>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: you're deleting all the options with `$('select').html('')` on every iteration ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry about the mistake done in pasting and rearranging the code, It's before the $.each iterator and it still doesn't work

Comment: And what does the console logs inside the `each` show, do they actually show the text for each option

Comment: @adeneo yes they do show what i need to be appended as options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery

Comment: @boomcode tried that method as well. Still doesn't work. I guess the problem somwhere else other than appending part as I tried several methods of appending and neither one of them worked

Comment: As long as the data is in the correct format, it should work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/mxtut6kq/1/, you have to check your data more thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

```js
function f1(){    $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'sessions',
                data: { date: date },
                success: function (data) {
                    var sessions = data['sessions'];
                    console.log(sessions);
                    $('select').html('');
                    $.each(sessions, function (i, session) {                            
                        $('select').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: session[0],
                            text : session[1]
                        }));
                        console.log(i);
                        console.log(session[1]);
                    });
                  
                  
                  
                   }
                });
}

var data ={
  "sessions" : [{"value":"value 1","text":"Option 1"},
                {"value":"value 2","text":"Option 2"},
                {"value":"value 3","text":"Option 3"},
                {"value":"value 4","text":"Option 4"},
                {"value":"value 5","text":"Option 5"}]
}


function fillSelect(){
  
  var sessionList=data.sessions;
  $('#session12').empty();
  var msg='';
  console.log(sessionList.length);
  for(i=0;i<sessionList.length;i++){
    var bean=sessionList[i];
    msg+='<option value="'+bean.value+'">'+bean.text+'</option>';
  }              
  $('#session12').html(msg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="sessionDiv" class="input-field"  style="padding:10px">
    <select class="black-text text-lighten-1" name="session" id="session12" >
        <option  value="0" disabled selected>Choose your preferred session</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="fillSelect()"> click to fill</button>
    <label for="session" class="purple-text text-lighten-2"> Session :</label>
  </div>                                       
</div>
```

If response of async request you are getting in `data` is similar to what i have written in data variable in snippet then my way of generating the `option` will work just fine. If response you are getting is exactly same as i have shown in data(by that i mean structure of the variable) then you can simply replace all your code in `ajax` function with my code in `fillSelect` function

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response, it was not initializing select in materialize CSS.