# How to put this JSON response into a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to put this data I get back from the server into a dropdown list but don't know how to do it since each object name starts with a random ID. This is what I am trying to do here:

```
 $("#CampaignOpenActionSubscriber_campaign_id").change(function() {
   var el = $(this);

   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "Dropdownlist",
     data: 'csrf_token=' + $('meta[name=csrf-token-value]').attr('content') +'&Selectedcampaign_id=' + el.val(),
     success: function (response) {
       var jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
       for(var i=0; i< jsonResponse.length; i++){
         $("#selectCourse").append(
           $('<option>').text(jsonResponse[i]).val(jsonResponse[i])
         );               
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

and this is what I get back from my JSON response... :

```
 {288878: "FOO", 288881: "BAZZ", 288882: "YOLLO"}
```

How would I put this into a dropdown list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use a `for.. in` loop to iterate over the keys of the object returned from your AJAX call. Try this:

```js
var jsonResponse = {
  288878: "FOO",
  288881: "BAZZ",
  288882: "YOLLO"
}

var html = '';
for (var key in jsonResponse) {
  html += '<option value="' + key + '">' + jsonResponse[key] + '</option>';
}
$("#selectCourse").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCourse"></select>
```

Also note that `JSON.parse()` is redundant in your AJAX `success` handler as jQuery will deserialise the response for you when JSON is detected. You may just need to add `dataType: 'json'` to the options if this does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the `jsonResponse` object using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and populate all the select options with [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Code:

```js
var $select = $('#selectCourse'),
    jsonResponse = {288878: "FOO", 288881: "BAZZ", 288882: "YOLLO"};

$.each(jsonResponse, function(key, value) {
    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectCourse">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```
var options = '';
for( var key in jsonResponse){
   options += '<option value ="key">' + jsonResponse[key] +'</option>
};
$("#selectCourse").html(options)
```

Comment: This seems to have some pretty fundamental syntax issues...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah, misstyped from the phone, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can use `$.each( object, function(key, value){})` to iterate an object

```js
var data = {288878: "FOO", 288881: "BAZZ", 288882: "YOLLO"};

$.each(data, function(prop, val){
   $('select').append( $('<option>',{text:val, value:prop}))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```