# JQuery Select Option to Show Another Select Option Then Show Data on that Second Select Option

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I need help for this. I want to create a select option where it will show a second select option. With that second select option I will select options there that will display data in a id. The data will be came from the 1st select option and to the second select option. Thank you very much in advance.
.
.
So far these are my codes that I created.

**students.php**

```
<div class="text-center" align="center">
                        <select id="ch_br_LdSubs" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; text-align: center !important;">
                            <option value="">-- select branch --</option>
                            <option value="MBC">MinSCAT Bongabong Campus</option>
                            <option value="MMC">MinSCAT Main Campus</option>
                            <option value="MCC">MinSCAT Calapan City Campus</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 10px;"></div>
                    <div id="printArea">
                        <div class="scroll-x">
                            <div id="branchData"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**ajax.js**
$(document).ready(function(){

```
/* Load the Students for a Specifed Branch and Course */
$('#showStdsByCourse').change(function(){

    var course = $(this).val();
    var branch = $('#ch_br_LdSubs').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'actions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {action: 'showStudents', branch: branch, course: course},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result)
        {
            $('studentsData').html(result);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('Failed to load students!');
        }

    });

});

/* Load the Branch Data for a Specified Branch */
$('#ch_br_LdSubs').change(function(){

    var branch = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'actions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {action: 'showBranchData', branch: branch},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result)
        {
            $('#branchData').html(result);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('Failed to load student data!');
        }

    });

});

/* Load the Courses for a Specified Branch */
$('#selectedBranch_loadCourse').change(function(){

    var branch = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'actions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {action: 'loadSubjectsPerBranch', branch: branch},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result)
        {
            $('#loadCourseByBranch').html(result);

        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('Failed to load courses!');
        }
    });

});
```

});

**This are the codes I put on the class I've created**

```
public function showBranchData($branch) {

        try {

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE branch = :branch");
            $stmt->bindparam(':branch', $branch);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() != null) {
                $branch_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                ?>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><?php print($branch_data['branch']) ?> Students</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <select id="showStdsByCourse" class="form-control" style="width: 200px">
                        <?php

                            $courses = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE branch = :branch");
                            $courses->bindparam(":branch", $branch);
                            $courses->execute();

                            if ($courses->rowCount() != null) {

                                echo '<option value="">-- select course --</option>';

                                while ($courseData = $courses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php print($courseData['course_acronym']) ?>"><?php print($courseData['course_name']) ?></option>
                                    <?php

                                }
                            } else {

                                ?>
                        <option value="">-- no courses yet --</option>
                                <?php
                            }

                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <span id="text"></span>
                    <div id="studentsData"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <?php

            } else {
                ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                No student data added yet!
            </div>
                <?php

            }

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {

            echo $ex->getMessage();
            return false;

        }

    }

    public function showStudents($branch, $course) {

        try {

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE branch = :branch AND course = :course");
            $stmt->bindparam(":branch", $branch);
            $stmt->bindparam(":course", $course);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() != null) {
                echo 'Student Data';
            } else {

                ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">No student data added yet!</div>
                <?php

            }

        } catch (PDOException $ex) {

            echo $ex->getMessage();
            return false;

        }

    }
```

Comment: could you add sample you tried so far with some better description to have a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

With that information I only can help you giving you some ideas. For what are you saying I would use JQuery getting the information from the first select to create the new options in the second select. If you need to search the information for the new options inside the database you will have to use Ajax to get the information.

Take a look in these questions. It could help you.

[What is the best way to add options to a select from as a JS object with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery)

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.