# Append fails to add option to dynamically loaded option list with optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Appending a single `option` to a dynamically loaded `select` fails without any error. This is jQuery code

```
$("#problem").load("docType.html");
$("#problem").append("<option value='All'>All</option>");
```

This loads options with **option group** from the external file successfully but fails to append the `'All'` option. No error or warning though !

`docType.html contents`

```
<optgroup label="Billing">
<option value="Incorrect Bill" selected="selected">Incorrect Bill</option>
<option value="High Bill">High Bill</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Other">
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: What is the contents of "docType.html"?

Comment: [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous, so you're appending before the HTML is loaded.

Comment: @gforce301 details added, plz check.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan plz suggest a solution

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ there is a complete function to `load`. If it stll does not work, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery

Comment: Read the documentation. You can provide a complete function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a callback because `load` function makes an async request.

```
$("#problem").load("docType.html", "", function() {
    $(this).append("<option value='All'>All</option>");
});
```

## Resource

- [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 3):

The `load()` method has an optional callback parameter.

You can use it here like

```
$("#problem").load("docType.html",, function (){
    $("#problem").append("<option value='All'>All</option>")
});
```

What happens is that jQuery starts loading docType.html and appends the All option to `#problem`. But this append ends before the docType.html loads.

After it loads it overwrites the original content with the All option.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You forgot to put the `,` before function. It works now :) Thanks