# Append the values to select box from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append the values from jquery to select box .

The html side is shown below

```
<select class="form-control prod" name="SalesPerson" id="SalesPerson"  required>
  <!-- <option value="">Select Sales Person</option> -->
</select>
```

Code Snippet of Ajax is shown below

```
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#SalesPerson').append("<option value='" + data.admin_id + "'>" + data.fname + "</option>");
  });
}
});
```

When i do `console.log(data);`

I get this output below

```
[{"admin_id":"206","fname":"FLYJAC-1BR","lname":""},{"admin_id":"252","fname":"KAMAL","lname":"G"},{"admin_id":"253","fname":"WILLIAM","lname":"S"}]
```

But the data is not appending to the select box . Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call?

Comment: I will be because the params of $.each is key, value not data. data is an array.

Comment: try value.admin_id not data.admin_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to add options to a select from as a JS object with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`dataType: 'json'` ***need to be added to your ajax call***

2.`data.admin_id` need to be `value.admin_id` and so on for other.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
data = [{"admin_id":"206","fname":"FLYJAC-1BR","lname":""},{"admin_id":"252","fname":"KAMAL","lname":"G"},{"admin_id":"253","fname":"WILLIAM","lname":"S"}];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $('#SalesPerson').append("<option value='" + value.admin_id + "'>" + value.fname + "</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control prod" name="SalesPerson" id="SalesPerson"  required>
 <!-- <option value="">Select Sales Person</option> -->

</select>
```

***For your code need to be (As you said that you want to remove old options and then need to add new options):-***

```
success: function(data){
    var option_html = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        option_html += "<option value='" + value.admin_id + "'>" + value.fname + "</option>";
    });
    $('#SalesPerson').html(option_html);
}
```

***Note:-***

if you don't have `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call then before `$.each()` code do:-

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: This function is added for onchange of select am passing the id and retrieving the data and appending it to another select box, Now whats happening is wen i change the first select box the values are getting displayed if i change it second time the old values are not erasing/clearing. how to clear that?

Comment: @ShreyasBandimat check my `For your code need to be (As you said that you want to remove old options and then need to add new options)`section code and try that. Thanks.