# jQuery performance: Chain appends or append multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, append

I was wondering which of those is more performant, and more importantly *why*?

```
$('a').append(
    $('<b></b>').text('1'),
    $('<b></b>').text('2'),
    $('<b></b>').text('3'));
```

and

```
$('a')
    .append($('<b></b>').text('1'))
    .append($('<b></b>').text('2'))
    .append($('<b></b>').text('3'));
```

where `a` and `<b>` are an arbitrary selector and tag. As far as I was able to tell from trying them out, they both function in exactly the same manner.

Relevant question: [What is the best way to add options to a select from as a JS object with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery)

**Edit:**

The reason I was asking this question was to know whether I should structure appends as:

```
texts = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$a = $('a');
$a.append(...texts.map(function(o){ return $('<b></b>').text(o); }));
```

or as:

```
texts = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$a = $('a');
for (o in texts) {
    $a.append($('<b></b>').text(o));
}
```

The latter one is more intuitive, and I believe most programmers would choose to write it, when the earlier one performs better.

Comment: `$('a').append('<b>123</b>');` or `$('a').html('<b>123</b>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a benchmarking tool to test this. I used JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/so-question

[image]

The results show that the first case is much faster. I believe it is because that jQuery does a lot of initialization, checking, and compatibility work every time you call a function that works with an element, that is, `.append()`.

The first case only calls `.append()` once, whereas the second case calls `.append()` three times. In general, the less function calls you make, the faster your code will be.

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right, the reason is that `append(a,b,c)` just checks the validity of `$('a.test')` once, while `.append(a).append(b).append(c)` has to check it thrice?

Comment: Correct, yes. You'll save even more time by doing `.append('<b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b>')` too for example

Comment: The numbers are just an example. .text() is used specifically to allow for something like .text('<b></b>') not adding a child element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Edited my question to reflect why I was asking a seemingly useless question. :)