# why is my option tag not appending on dynamically generated select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a dynamically generated `select` tag and then after that, I have to make an ajax call to query some values and loop thru it and dynamically generate the `options` tag. But for some reason, I cant append an `option` tag to my select tag. This is not the issue of asynchronicity right?

```
const firstElemTd = $('#none td:first-child');

firstElemTd.append(`<select id="the-select"></select>`);

const selectTag = $(`#the-select`);

$.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, balyu) {
          selectTag.append($('<option>', {value: balyu.name}).text(balyu.name));
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: If you check console are you getting any errors? What does your response object look like?

Comment: no. there's no errors that whats buggin me.

Comment: Have you inspected `firstElmTd` to see what it actually is? Do you see your select tag added properly? And definitely check your response object.

Comment: @scrappedcola yep. I fixed it by just putting the select tag on the html instead of creating it dynamically. but the id and name should be dynamic so I just added the id and name attr on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the selectTag as a jQuery object first. You can then append to it.

```js
$(function(){
    const $firstElemTd = $('#none td:first-child');
    const $selectTag = $('<select></select>');
    //append the selectTag to the td
    $firstElemTd.append($selectTag);
    //now that the selectTag is a distinct jQuery object you can append to it. EG:
    var response = [{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}];
    $.each(response, function(key, balyu) {
      $selectTag.append($('<option/>').val(balyu.name).text(balyu.name));
    });

/* The same thing in the ajax response should work too.
(commented out here for the snippet)
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, balyu) {
          $selectTag.append($('<option/>').val(balyu.name).text(balyu.name));
        });
      }
    });
   */ 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="none"><tr><td></td></table>
```

Comment: holy crap this works. thank you. I didn't know that you need to create the tag first before appending. I thought It will do that automagically. lols. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing your $.each incorrectly

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
     $.each(response, function(key, balyu) {
        selectTag.append($('<option></option>', 
              {value: balyu.name, 
               text: balyu.name}
        ));
     });
  }
});
```

You could also go with another approach:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, balyu) {        
            selectTag.append($('<option></option>'
                .val(balyu.name)
                .text(balyu.name));
        });
    }
});
```

Either way will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: are you talking about `text` method? I got it from here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: You grabbed the question, not the actual answer.  Look at the answer right below that, there's a third option that I haven't given.

Comment: Your second approach needs a closing `>` on your option tag.

Comment: Thanks @scrappedcola.  Fixed.

Comment: Don't you need a closing parenthesis? eg: `selectTag.append($('<option></option>')`

Comment: it's a derived answer from the actual answer. he said This is a cleaned up and simplified version of [matdumsa's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-as-a-js-object-with-jquery/171007#171007):

Comment: @Moob - Yes, that's correct.  I'll update.  Sorry, copied and pasted from OP and didn't fix. LOL

Comment: @aRtoo - Feel free to try either solution, and see if they work for you.  If not, let me know what's failing.

Comment: I think you cant append on a dynamically generated tag. because I've set the select directly on the HTML and then have the same method on to generate options.

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code, and then we can modify from there.

Comment: its all cool. thanks though. I think you cant just append on JS generated tag.